# chmod 600 on an apache server web file still allowing access to from world

Tags: linux, security, permissions

My webserver is running as www-data, but for some reason this image file can be seen from the web without problem.  Here are the permissions/ownership:

```
ls -alht /var/www/html/file.jpeg
-rw------- 1 www-data www-data
```

If I do a chmod 000 on that file, it cannot be seen as would be expected.

I'm completely stumped by this, anyone have any idea what is going on? Many thanks.

Comment: Are you clearing cache on the client so the browser is not loading a cached image from local storage?  Also, the web server might (possibly) be doing its own caching so also try restarting httpd.  And finally if you are using a content delivery network in between that might also be caching.  Try -rw----- with a new file name.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have tried access from 4 different browsers/devices which hadn't viewed the file previously.  I have also tried restarting the server, and there is no content delivery network - I'm running the server on a localhost and accessing it from other web browsers within the LAN.

Comment: Really odd, I have performed the exact same permissions changes on another webserver on on openbsd system and it's exactly the same - can still access the files.  That one is live on the web.

Comment: Who is the owner of the file, and who is the web server running as?  Apparently they are the same user then.  If the web server has access it does not matter who is asking the web server for it.  If you want to enforce website user access that needs some sort of access management system to serve the files.

Comment: The owner is www-data and for openbsd it is www. I found a fix, I dont know why this works and the other doesn't, but putting permissions on its actual directory works as expected but on the files themselves - nope! I'm still baffled why that is the case though, clearly I know less about file permissions than what I thought I knew. You don't happen to know why directory permissions are working as expected here but targetting just the files doesn't?

Comment: Nope, that's an interesting question though :)

Comment: What permissions did you set on the directory? If you used 0600 then yes it will work. This is because you have removed the permission necessary for  `www-data` to navigate into to the directory, which will also prevent `www-data` from reading/writing to that directory. Basically that directory is of no use to you in that state. Apache allows you to restrict access to files and directories via the config. See https://serverfault.com/questions/267440/apache2-how-to-restrict-access-to-files-in-documentroot

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 2):

Linux permissions work only in the context of linux users not website users.

Your webserver is a single app running as a user:group identity (www-data:www-data) within the linux system. That's all that matters. If your webserver can read/execute the file then technically anybody who visits the website can unless your website app explicitly prohibits them according to ip, app based credentials or similar.

The only thing you can effect by changing permissions on the Linux OS level is to prevent the webserver from reading the file or serving it to anybody or to make so that other *linux* users on the same system cannot access them. This is particularly important when using shared hosting, where multiple *linux* users represent many different people using the same Linux server.

http://linuxcommand.org/lts0070.php

If you want to prevent a file on your webserver from being served by your webserver to the public, you should configure your .htaccess file or similar website conf file such as /etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.conf to disallow access to a particular location.

If you are using nginx as a webserver then your conf file should be found under /etc/nginx/conf.d or /etc/nginx/sites-available or similar

http://www.ducea.com/2006/08/11/apache-tips-tricks-deny-access-to-some-folders/

Alternatively you can restrict access via password using htpasswd

https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PasswordBasicAuth